# Java Swing Insert Key Mnemonic

Tags: java, windows, swing

I have a complex Java Swing GUI application which defines a mnemonic key for the "Insert" button:

```
insertButton.setMnemonic( KeyEvent.VK_INSERT );
```

However, when I type `Alt`+`Insert` this application's File menu gains focus.  I changed the mnemonic key code:

```
insertButton.setMnemonic( KeyEvent.VK_0 );
```

and this behavior does not occur when I type `Alt`+`0`.

How do I define the `Insert` mnemonic key in a way that consumes the `Alt` `KeyEvent`?  (Or do mnemonic key bindings only work properly for keys which generate `KEY_TYPED` events?)

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for better help sooner

Comment: See also [*How to Use Actions*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html).

Comment: Thanks.  After reviewing the documentation and code once more, I've isolated the root cause of the problem (which appears to be specific to the program, not to Java Swing -- the `VK_INSERT` `KeyEvent` was being consumed by the application).

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. For reference, you can [answer (or delete) your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/163188); an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) is always welcome.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll make an SSCCE tonight if possible (hopefully there's a way to simplify my example from thousands of lines of code to under 100 such that it merits posting).